# How to connect Fennec with eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse, perl, fennec

I'm trying to checkout the Mozilla Fennec code and connect it with Eclipse for making some changes and deplyoing it on the device.

I'm referring this link. Visit: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android#Connecting_Eclipse_to_Android_Build_tree

I have checked out the whole code and added path as required in mozconfig_values file. When I execute run ./create_projects.pl, it gives me error with:

> No command 'run' found, did you mean:

I think I'm mentioning the path in mozconfig_values file as wrong. Please guide me to overcome this problem or tell me how to run "Perl" file on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

You literally typed `run ./create_projects.pl`, but that is wrong. Your shell/operating system is complaining rightfully that there is not command `run`.

Type `perl ./create_projects.pl` instead.

Comment: I have tried that command to, but I'm getting the same error that "No command 'perl' found".

Comment: But the package `perl-base`, which contains the perl binary, is marked as essential. How'd you manage to break Ubuntu that Perl doesn't work?

Comment: I couldn't give the answer to that because I don't have deep knowledge about Ubuntu. But the error was there, when ever I tried to run these commands.

Comment: I see no programming problem here anymore, the question is off-topic for this site. Get further help at http://askubuntu.com

Comment: BTW ./create_projects.pl should work fine without putting perl in front of it as its marked executable in the git repo and has a:
 #!/usr/bin/perl

As you pointed out the original poster has somehow badly broken their ubuntu install and needs to consult on askubuntu instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

Type

> ./create_projects.pl

without anything before it